# Add the elements of a file into a class object

Tags: c++, oop, file-io

I have this file that contains a name cost unit and qty of items that I need to read from and put it into a class object I want each line in the file to be a its own object [the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jblGl.png)

This is the constructor for my class

```
Cost::Cost(string name, double cost, string unit, double qty) : Item(name, unit)
{
    this->getName() = name;
    this->cost= cost;
    this->getUnit() = unit;
    this->qty = qty;
}
```

I tried to do this

```
ifstream inFile("data.txt");

    string line, word, name, unit;
    double cost = 0.0, qty = 0.0;
    vector<string> itemStr;
    vector<Cost> itemObj;
    

    while (inFile)
    {
        while (getline(inFile, line))
        {
            std::stringstream stream(line);
            while (getline(stream, word, delim))
            {
                itemStr.push_back(word);
            }

            name = itemStr.at(0);
            cost = std::stod(itemStr.at(1));
            unit = itemStr.at(2);
            qty = std::stod(itemStr.at(3));
            

            Cost c(name, cost, unit, qty);

            itemObj.push_back(c);
            
        }
        
    }
```

but it would only put the first line into the object multiple times when I want each line into its own object

Comment: You could remove the outer `while (inFile)` loop without changing anything

Comment: @john i've tried it and it still only puts the first line in the file multiple times instead of each line

Comment: Yes I realised the bug shortly after I'd made that comment, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is here

```
vector<string> itemStr;
vector<Cost> itemObj;    

while (inFile)
{
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        std::stringstream stream(line);
        while (getline(stream, word, delim))
        {
            itemStr.push_back(word);
        }
```

it should be

```
vector<Cost> itemObj;    

while (inFile)
{
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        vector<string> itemStr;
        std::stringstream stream(line);
        while (getline(stream, word, delim))
        {
            itemStr.push_back(word);
        }
```

In your version the `itemStr` vector just grows and grows, but you keep reusing the same four elements at the start of the vector, that's why you get the same object added repeatedly. In my version the `itemStr` vector starts at size zero for each new line.

It's good practice to declare variables as close to where you use them as possible (instead of declaring them at the start of the function). It's cleaner and make bugs like this less likely.

You can also remove the `while (inFile)` loop which does nothing.

Comment: writing a `>>` rather than using the vector could also help to make the code more clear (implementation could still use a vector though)